# "A swashed H" - valid description?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

Can the typography term "swash", meaning a flourish on a letter or character, be used as a verb?

Comment: Absolutely any word in English can be used as a verb. There are no words that can't.

Comment: [v. swashed, swash·ing, swash·es](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/swash)

Comment: In your example, I think it's actually an adjective, which is certainly OK.

Comment: @RegDwigнt When I tell you I am going 'withing' on Saturday, and will 'by' repeatedly on Sunday, and 'what' my toes on Monday, I take it you will be clear as to what my week-end is going to be like!

Comment: *Tenement landlords were cruel and invisible, hiding behind their curlicued, ampersanded companies, their ornate windows in St Enoch Square, ...*

Comment: @WS2 my not knowing the *meaning* of these verbs is completely orthogonal to whether they are verbs. There are thousands of words you don't know the meaning of. That doesn't magically strip them of their grammatical function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A swash, in the context you've indicated, is a noun, so technically you cannot make it a verb.  However, I'm sure if you don't care too much about proper grammar, people would understand what you are referring to and accept it, so long as they know what the typographical version of the word swash means.

A word of warning, there is a variation of swash which is a verb and a noun, but has a very different meaning.

swash  (swsh, swôsh)
n.

1.

- A splash of water or other liquid hitting a solid surface.
- The sound of such a splash.

2.

- A narrow channel through which tides flow.
- A bar over which waves wash freely.
- See uprush.

4.

- Swagger or bluster.
- A swaggering or blustering person.

v. swashed, swash·ing, swash·es

v.intr.

- To strike, move, or wash with a splashing sound.
- To swagger.

v.tr.

- To splash (a liquid).
- To splash a liquid against.

[Definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/swash)

Comment: I've decided that valid or invalid, the sentence was a little vague. Therefore I've reworded it to avoid this odd use of the word `swash`.